# Help installing Symfony plugin

Tags: php, plugins, symfony1, installation

Hello can somebody write or point to a good symfony plugin installation tutorial. Here is the problem, I have a symfony 1.2 application and I'm trying to install the LightWindow plugin, which run on Prototype.

The thing is: I dont have PEAR installed, and due to proxy limitations I don't think I can, but there is a way to install symfony plugins, which is copying it in the plugins folder,  enabling it in the application's config file and running plublish assets, I did all that successfuly and plugin still won't run. Here is a small piece of the code I'm using in the layout:

```
<?php use_helper('LightWindow'); ?>
.
.
.
<?php foreach ( $secImages as $image ): ?>
                <div class="image-slot">
                    <?php echo lw_image(image_tag(sfConfig::get('app_image_vo_dir') . $image->getPhoto()),
                            sfConfig::get('app_image_vo_dir') . $image->getPhoto()); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```

Hope anybody can help.

Also this code doesn't run directly in the layout, the main layout includes it using Ajax

[EDIT]

It works in non ajax environment, but when I try to run it using ajax, it doesn't work, I suspect that the problem is that the LightWindow script checks for a tags on document ready, and since this content is loaded via ajax, it doesn't sees it!

Changing to a non aJax environment is not possible, since is the way my client wants it, besides, no ajax in 2010? almost sci-fi! :)

Any help will be terrific!

Comment: how did you copy it to your plugin folder? As a tar or Zip file? Or did you uncompress it before?

Comment: I uncompressed it, and I did the whole installation steps, so far; nothing!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: That's the whole deal! I don't get any error message, I click on the pics and then it just opens the image, but no LightBox! The JS neede are not included in the response!

Comment: Does it work in a non-ajax template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*lw_image()* helper adds required javascript and css assets to the response. As you make ajax requests those are added to the ajax response.

Firstly browsers wouldn't handle it. Secondly, it's not returned by symfony in head section anyway as ajax response is not decorated with the layout.

To process javascript/css files you have to add it to the page which makes ajax calls.

Comment: You're right! sorry it took me so long to reply, but I had lots of work and I couldnt dedicate much time to symfony. Thanks a lot for your help. One thing tough, I had to make a call to lightwindow.prototype.initialize(); to get light window up and running after the ajax call